# PHP Composer update "cannot allocate memory" error (using Laravel 4)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I just can't solve this one.

I'm on Linode 1G RAM basic plan. Trying to install a package via Composer and it's not letting me. My memory limit is set to "-1" on PHP.ini

Is there anything else I can do to get this installed?

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing thujohn/rss (dev-master df80a7d)
    Downloading: 100%         
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory' in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:975
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'proc_open(): fo...', 'phar:///usr/loc...', 975, Array)
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(975): proc_open('stty -a | grep ...', Array, NULL, NULL, NULL, Array)
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(853): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getSttyColumns()
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(818): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalDimensions()
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(752): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalWidth()
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/com in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 975

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory' in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:975
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'proc_open(): fo...', 'phar:///usr/loc...', 975, Array)
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(975): proc_open('stty -a | grep ...', Array, NULL, NULL, NULL, Array)
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(853): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getSttyColumns()
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(818): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalDimensions()
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(752): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalWidth()
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/com in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 975
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

A bit old but just in case someone new is looking for a solution, updating your PHP version can fix the issue.

Also you should be committing your composer.lock file and doing a composer install on a production environment which is less resource intensive.

More details here:
https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1898#issuecomment-23453850

Comment: BRILLIANT! That worked. I didn't upgrade my PHP, but committing composer.lock file and updating installed all things properly. Thank you.

Comment: Late to the party, but I simply switched off Apache and MySQL. There is a reason I am using a 512MB RAM VPS, don't want to spend monies.

Comment: Updating PHP is not a solution. I have 7.0.21, and still get this error.

Comment: @Kumar's solution worked for me. Super easy and like most things, obvious in hindsight :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Saved me a bunch of time.

Comment: As I know swap files are not good for SSD disks. It is better to increase memory_limit with the update command: run php -dmemory_limit=750M composer update --no-scripts --prefer-dist

Answer (score 449):

Looks like you runs out of swap memory,
try this

```
/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
/sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
/sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

as mentioned by @BlackBurn027 on comments below, this solution was described in [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors)

Comment: You sir, are a genius - its not a php issue and removing files will no help. I have to follow your instructions (with sudo) on my VPS. This is the only one useful answer here for VPS owners.

Comment: This worked for me too and I didn't have to update my PHP. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me. With this solution I increased memory_limit from the default 128M to 512M

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors as mentioned by the source

Comment: that works for me without reinstalling the PHP. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me but I'm confused what those commands are actually doing, can someone explain them?

Comment: sometimes 1024 is not enough... Use 2048 instead

Comment: I had the same issue with my AWS EC2 with Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP 7.0.1 and your answer solved my problem. Kudos!!!

Comment: This happened to me on ec2 as well. T2 micro, AWS-Linux AMI

Comment: I received a memory error while running “composer update” on as Raspberry Pi 3b+ and solved this by creating a swap like described above. Thanks a lot for this :-)

Comment: But this solution goes away if I reboot Ubuntu 18. I am on AWS EC2 T3 Mini

Comment: I'd already tried to switch off Apache and Mysql, but it didn't work. With this suggestion, it worked great!!! Thank you so much, it saved me.

Comment: Excellent! From what I can see it basically creates/resizes the swap file right?

Comment: @JaberAlNahian you can make a permanent swap please check here  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I will be forever in your dept, If you ever came to Iran let me know, I will invite you to a lunch (btw don't come to iran it's dangerous)

Comment: how about docker container? should I do above as usual or should I first go to container bash?

Answer (score 127):

As composer troubleshooting guide [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors)
This could be happening because the VPS runs out of memory and has no Swap space enabled.

```
free -m
```

To enable the swap you can use for example:

```
sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

Or if above not worked then you can try create a swap file

```
sudo fallocate -l 2G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Comment: thanks alot without upgrading php5 to php7 this worked

Comment: It gave the error again but running composer update after that worked fine.

Comment: And you can check the [official document][2]

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-fai%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20led-error

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works for me. (Digital Ocean $10 Server)

Comment: Setting the swap is the best solution. If you just up the memory with `php -dmemory_limit` then you will still run out of memory if your machine doesn't have enough, there is no way around that apart from enabling swap.

Comment: i was trying to install git on an ec2 instance without success, and that fixed the issue...
the command /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1 was giving permission error but it worked anyway

Answer (score 40):

I have faced the same issue. I am on a AWS Free Microinstance which has less memory. I always try one of the below options and it always works *(Before all this please check if you have the latest version of composer installed)*

```
sudo php -dmemory_limit=750M composer.phar update
```

or remove the contents of the vendor folder and try composer update.

```
sudo rm -rf vendor
sudo php -dmemory_limit=750M composer.phar update --no-scripts --prefer-dist
sudo php artisan --dump-autoload
```

The second option tries to update all the components, if there is no update, it picks up the package from the cache else picks up from the dist

**Note: Please change the memory limit as per your choice.**

or

Create a **swap partition** and try. Swap partition is the portion of the hard drive that linux uses as virtual memory when it runs out of physical memory. It's similar to the windows swap file only instead of using an actual file, linux uses a partition on the hard drive instead.

Hope this helps

Comment: I dropped the memory limit down to 500M and composer installed what I needed.

Comment: you can also use an actual swap file instead of a partition. see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/

Comment: Had same problem on my Digital Ocean account even at 250M I also had to stop Apache and MySQL first before I could run it

Comment: tristanbailey your solution worked, thanks! Before I stopped mysql and apache I couldn't update, even by setting the php memory limit.

Comment: When I run `sudo php -dmemory_limit=750M composer.phar update
` I got this error `Could not open input file: composer.phar` please help

Answer (score 16):

Easy, type this commands:

`rm -rf vendor/`

`rm -rf composer.lock`

`php composer install --prefer-dist`

Should work for low memory machines

Comment: Worked for me. I have written a comprehensive answer over here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850332/laravel-composer-update-runs-out-of-memory/26850776#26850776

Comment: It's not working. And this deleted all my vendor folder. It's wrong!

Comment: What is the problem delete the vendor? just run install/update again...

Comment: Deleting vendor isn't entirely wrong, though it does break the site and keeps it in the broken state if the install still doesn't work. However, deleting the lock file on production machines is not advised. You should be committing your lock file and only installing, not updating. In fact, by deleting the lock file, you're forcing Composer to install from the json file, which is where the memory-intensive processes come from (determining which version of what to install).

Comment: It's ok to follow this if you are not in a production environment, since it will break the project until composer is done with the installation

Answer (score 13):

Here are the steps to fix the problem:
(instant fast SWAP file allocation method used)

Server SWAP Setup (Ubuntu 16.04 SWAP to Fix Out of Memory Errors)

Check if you have swap already, memory and disk size:

```
    sudo swapon -s
    free -m
    df -h
```

Make swap file: (change 1G to 4G if you want 4GB SWAP memory)

```
    sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile
```

Check swap file:

```
    ls -lh /swapfile
```

Assign Swap File:

```
    sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
    sudo mkswap /swapfile
    sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Check if swap OK, memory and disk size:

```
    sudo swapon -s
    free -m
    df -h
```

Attach Swap File on System Restart:

```
    sudo nano /etc/fstab
        /swapfile   none    swap    sw    0   0
```

Adjust Swap File Settings:

```
    cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
    cat /proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure

    sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10
    sudo sysctl vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50

    sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

SWAP File Priority: (0-100% => 0: Don't put to swap,  100: Put on SWAP and free the RAM)

```
        vm.swappiness=10
```

Remove inode from cache: (100: system removes inode information from the cache too quickly)

```
        vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 50
```

Comment: I don't know what I have to do on the last step `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`, So, I skip it then restart Nginx and then do `composer install` (previously I've removed the vendor directory) and it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I had a same issue on vagrant. I fixed it by allcate more memory.

```
 config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
 end
```

Comment: Solved this issue for me too. Note that in vagrant 2.x instead of `vb.customize ...` you can do `vb.memory = 1024`.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the workaround that I found that works for me every time:

```
df -h 
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=1024
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=1024
mkswap /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
echo 'echo "/swapfile  none  swap  defaults  0  0" >> /etc/fstab' | sudo sh

free -m

confirm u see your swap there:
total used free shared buffers cached
Mem: 494 335 158 0 19 62
-/+ buffers/cache: 254 240
Swap: 1023 3 1020

watch free -m
```

Comment: Wowwow, posting the commands without explaining what they do is probably dangerous! Although I can definitively say it would work on most systems. Basically you are creating allocating Swap space so that the HD can be used as RAM.

Here is a comprehensive guide on how to do that explaining each command: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Thank you for the clarification of the commands, it is nice to know what the script actually do before you execute it. But in the same way it is not nice how you are promoting digital ocean and your tutorial/blog post.

Comment: The tutorial is great, showing step by step with explanations!

Comment: Thank you! You instructions help me to install Drupal Presto for 1GB RAM server. I have change 1024 to 2048.

Answer (score 7):

I tried by just deleting the **vendor folder** and **composer.lock** file and then i run the command `composer clear-cache` and then `composer install`. So it working without any error.

Answer (score 7):

Try that:

```
/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024

/sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1

/sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - especially: what have you changed comparing to the other answers that use the same approach? Is there any need to duplicate their answer?

Answer (score 5):

you can use the following to check your free (swap) memory

```
free -m

total used free shared buffers cached

Mem: 2048 357 1690 0 0 237
-/+ buffers/cache: 119 1928
Swap: 0 0 0
```

To enable the swap you can use for example:

```
/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
/sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
/sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

Comment: I used `free -m` and noticed that I had no memory, not even in swap .. then did `sudo reboot` and it worked

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a recurring issue with 1GB and smaller server instances. Apart from trying to shutdown processes and tweak swap settings, you could install on a local machine and upload.

Comment: yep. Funny thing is if I delete the whole project, do a fresh git pull and then do composer install, it seems to work. Strange.

Comment: Frustrating, I am deploying a few L4 projects to 1GB Linode instances and am now worried about hitting the memory ceiling.

Comment: An old link but may be of some use: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1104

Comment: The accepted answer is still the best way to go. You should commit composer.lock and then run an install instead of update on the production server.

Answer (score 3):

I increased the PHP `memory_limit` from the default **128M** to **512M** and restart the server. That solved the problem.

Comment: reboot shouldn't be needed as PHP doesn't runs as a service.

Comment: No but Apache does and thus it should be restarted in order to take effect...

Comment: it is needed, as apache loads the php modules

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes by self-updating composer it solves the problem

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

Cheers

Comment: This should be the first thing to try to fix the issue. I had problem with 1.3.3, self-update to 1.4.0 fixed the issue.

Tip: you could update your answer to cover also cover the use-case of `composer self-update`, if someone not-so-familiar with composer is to read this reply.

Comment: get permission denied when rename occurs

Answer (score 2):

I get into this situation most of the times so normally i used to follow the step of setting the swap memory.

But now i found a simple alternate trick which worked for me.

Run
    `composer update --no-dev` Other than `composer update`

Answer (score 2):

I solved the same problem in Vagrant.
I increased the value of **memory_limit**
and delete composer cache: **sudo rm -R ~/.composer**
and finally vagrant reload.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
/sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
/sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

This work for me on Centos 6

Comment: this worked for me on AWS Opsworks EC2 Instance Ubuntu 14.04!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make a swap and run composer command again. I hope it'll work for you.

```
 $ dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=512k
 $ mkswap /swapfile
 $ swapon /swapfile
 $ echo "/swapfile       none    swap    sw      0       0 " >> /etc/fstab
 $ echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
 $ chown root:root /swapfile
 $ chmod 0600 /swapfile
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I tried everything that was listed above. I was using Laravel and Vagrant with 4GB of memory and a swap, with memory limit set to -1. I deleted the vendor/ and tried other PHP-versions. Finally, I managed it to work by running

```
vagrant halt
vagrant up
```

And then composer install worked again as usual.

Answer (score 0):

have same problem with php composer.phar update on my 512mb hosting.

solved with **php composer.phar install**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using composer in wsl2.

Microsoft WSL team introduced a file called .wslconfig for tweaking WSL2 settings.

You basically have to create that file at %UserProfile%.wslconfig and set the settings below.

```
[wsl2]
memory=6GB  # Any size you feel like
swap=30GB
localhostForwarding=true
```

Restart your computer, and from now on, you won't have any problem with high memory consumption.

Hopefully, it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when Laravel ver 7,8 and composer ver 1, this error came out.
I updated the version of Composer to 2 and it was resolved.

```
composer self-update
```

Or

```
composer self-update --2
```

Back to previous version:

```
composer self-update --rollback
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue on the cheapest server (512MB RAM) hosted with [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=a2984a839658), and I was also running Jenkins CI on the same server. After I stopped the Jenkins instance the composer install command worked (well, to a point, it failed with the mcrypt extension missing besides already being installed!).

Maybe if you have another app running on the server, maybe its worth trying to stop it and re-running the command.

Answer (score -1):

edit php.ini file and increase memory_limit value.

> memory_limit=1G

will solve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
composer update

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
```

### > mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

Update memory on Server and require '4G' Change 4GB Ram [try to change server type or add more ram]

2 Files We need to edit

---

on command

```
# cd /var/www/html
# nano .htaccess
```

and edit `"memory_limit 756M”` to `4G`

---

Php ini on php 7.0

```
# cd ~
# php –-ini
# sudo nano /etc/php-7.0.ini
```

memory_limit = 128M to 4G

*#AWS #AMAZONLINUX #MAGENTO2 #PHP7.0*

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Changing anything in `.htaccess` does not affect `composer` after all, as this is not run through a webserver

Answer (score -1):

I use it for 500MB RAM and it works for me.

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer install
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

According to composer's documentation, Composer 1 used much more memory and upgrading to the latest version will give you much better and faster results.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors

Comment: Already suggested years ago. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32637848

Comment: @miken32 sorry, I can't find this answer on this question and that's why I posted it to help anyone encountering same issue

Comment: also @miken32 the command here stackoverflow.com/a/32637848 doesn't update to composer 2 as suggested in the composer article link posted above

Answer (score -2):

Please disable js bundling and increase memory. That should fix it. I fixed mine by disabling js bundling.

Thanks

Comment: Please share more details on your answer - why should disabling "js bundling" help when an error occurs on downloading a package (which happens way before any scripts are run)