# Out of memory error in 'Composer update' command inside docker container in Aws ec2 instance

Tags: laravel, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, composer-php

I have tried to run 'composer update' command inside docker container in Aws ec2 instance. But I get this error

```
  mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

  mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

  Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 478179328) (tried to allocate 20996408 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php on line 462
```

I have tried using "memory_limit = -1" or "memory_limit = 2G" in the php configaration file.
I have also tried to run this command "php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer update" inside my docker container.
But it still shows the same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Composer update "cannot allocate memory" error (using Laravel 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116261/php-composer-update-cannot-allocate-memory-error-using-laravel-4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `composer update` in your local environment, then commit `composer.json` and `composer.lock` to your code repository, pull the changes in your ec2 instance and run `composer install`.

Commonly, low resource servers don't have enough RAM to run `composer update`. You're better off doing it in your local environment, and only using `composer install` on your server.

Comment: I have firstly run "composer update" in my local enviorment and the commit the code to github and then clone the project in Aws ec2 container. Then run "docker-compose up -d" to run the container and the instde the container run "composer update" command

Comment: Don't run `composer update` inside the container. That's your problem, and there's no real point. Run `composer install` instead.